# How do i know what triggered on change?

Tags: javascript, html, events, onchange

Is there a way to know what type of move triggered the [onChange](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/Events/change) event on an input type="number"

I explain :

[image]

I want to know if the change came from the "text" area or the "down and up arrows" area. Is it possible ?

Comment: Nope, you have to build your own input interface (The input, plus 2 arrows over it, as individual components with seperate IDs etc).

Comment: this is what i thought, but somehow i hoped there was a unknow property in the event object that will give me the thing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Event` object from the callback will not give you this information. But you may try this trick:

```js
const onChange = function(e) {
  if ($(this).data('_oldval') !== this.value) {
    console.log('from arrows')
  }

  $(this).removeData('_oldval');
};

const onKeyUp = function(e) {
  if (e.which >= 37 && e.which <= 40) {
    return onChange(e);
  }

  $(this).data('_oldval', this.value);
  
  console.log('from text field');
};

$('input').on('change', onChange);
$('input').on('keyup', onKeyUp);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number">
```

The same without jQuery:

```js
const onChange = function(e) {
  if (this.dataset) {
    if (this.dataset._oldval !== this.value) {
      console.log('from arrows')
    }
    
    delete this.dataset._oldval;
  }
};

const onKeyUp = function(e) {
  if (e.which >= 37 && e.which <= 40) {
    return onChange(e);
  }

  this.dataset._oldval = this.value;
  
  console.log('from text field');
};

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change', onChange);
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp);
```

```html
<input type="number">
```

Comment: scrollwheel triggers "from arrows" output :p

Comment: Nice one, but how the hell are you changing the input value with the wheel?? Makes nothing for me...

Comment: I don't see any changes with the scrollwheel. This solution is perfect ! thanks !

Comment: Must be a firefox thing

Comment: @KévinBibollet ... click on the input box ... use scroll wheel ... pretty basic stuff actually ... but that's a firefox thing, I guess chrome hasn't caught up

Comment: I am using Chrome, so I guess that's it.

Answer (score 2):

The `onchange` event will fire at every input only from the UI and up-down key inputs.
Otherwise, we must loose the focus, or press enter to trigger this event.

So we can check whether we are still the activeElement and thus fired from the UI, or not, and thus came from typing.
With the one exception of the Enter key...

```js
let enter_down = false;
inp.addEventListener('change', e => {
  if(enter_down || inp !== document.activeElement) {
    console.log('typing');
  }
  else {
    console.log('arrows');
  }
});

inp.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if(e.key === 'Enter') {
    enter_down = true;
  }
});
inp.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  if(e.key === 'Enter') {
    enter_down = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="inp">
```

Comment: Thank you, when i lauch the snippet if i use the array "typing" is log and not arrow. 
Kévin Bibollet write the solution i wanted

Comment: @MaximeGirou han! Firefox... right? They always have strange behavior with focusing inputs...

Comment: yep, Firefox :D

Comment: Firefox does not do anything strange with this code ... arrow when use arrow, typing when use keyboard, and arrow when use scrollwheel - just like the other answers

Comment: @JaromandaX no it actually fails in the case described by OP in FF: when initially blurred, clicking the arrows doesn't set the focus on the input. My code fails here, but I think it's unexpected that the focus isn't set on the input. Or are you saying it does set the focus on your OS? That could be, I'm experiencing it on macOs, and I know of at least [one bug that only affects macOs related to this.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1547926)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this with vanillaJavascript:

```js
//Define a flag to save if the user used the keyboard on the input or the right arrows
let keyUpFlag = false;

//each time a change on the input is made by using the keyboard, the keyUpFlag is set to true
function onKeyUp(event) {
  keyUpFlag = true;
}


//bind this callback funtion to the on change event of the input
function onChange(event) {
  // if the this flag is set to true, means that the user changed the input by using the keyboard, so by changing the text.
  if (keyUpFlag) {
   console.log("On change from text!");
  } else {
    //If not, means that used the the right arrows to change the value
   console.log("On change from the arrows!");
  }
  //sets again the flat to false in order to reset the on key value state
  keyUpFlag = false;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" onchange="onChange(event)" onkeyup="onKeyUp(event)">
```

Comment: scrollwheel triggers "from arrows" output :p

Comment: I don't get any log with "On change from text!" . otherwise Kévin Bibollet write the solution i wanted. Thanks you !